# Why is String [] giving different length and splitting the given string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have sample strings like:

> Data Management_Commercial IMS (Information Management System)
>
> Data Management_Non-structured Data Management (Text Documents, Paper Forms, etc.)

I am passing the strings from the jsp page via `input-move-boxes`. So in the jsp page I have:

```
List<KeyValuePair> leftDataManagementList = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>();
List<KeyValuePair> rightDataManagementList = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>();
rightDataManagementList.add(new KeyValuePair(attribute.getAttributeListName()+"_"+attribute.getAttributeListValue(), attribute.getAttributeListValue()));
leftDataManagementList.add(new KeyValuePair(attributeMaster.getAttributeListName()+"_"+attributeMaster.getAttributeListValue(), attributeMaster.getAttributeListValue()));
```

The `input-move-box` in this case is

```
<liferay-ui:input-move-boxes
            leftBoxName="availabledm"
            leftTitle="Data Management Available"
            leftList="<%=leftDataManagementList %>"
            rightBoxName="selecteddm"
            rightTitle="Data Management Selected"
            rightList="<%= rightDataManagementList%>"     
        />
```

In java class these are retrieved in `String[] selecteddm` variable.

```
String[] selecteddm = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "selecteddm");
```

**But I am passing one string at a time.**
So when I store the first string `Data Management_Commercial IMS (Information Management System)` in the variable. I get the expected results.

```
System.out.println("Length:" +selecteddm.length);//Length:1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selecteddm));//[Data Management_Commercial IMS (Information Management System)]

int count = 0;
for(String str:selecteddm){
     System.out.println(str);//Data Management_Commercial IMS (Information Management System)
     System.out.println(count++);//0
}
```

Now I get the problem with the second string `Data Management_Non-structured Data Management (Text Documents, Paper Forms, etc.)`, as it is splitting into separate strings after comma. In this case,

```
System.out.println("Length:" +selecteddm.length);//Length:3

//This print seems fine
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selecteddm));//[Data Management_Non-structured Data Management (Text Documents, Paper Forms, etc.)]

int count = 0;
for(String str:selecteddm){
   System.out.println(str);
   System.out.println(count++);
}
```

The loop in this case prints:

```
Data Management_Non-structured Data Management (Text Documents
0
Paper Forms
1
etc.)
2
```

Why is this exactly happening? As a result `str.split("_")[1]` on the string in second case generates `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. How can I avoid this and make it work like the string in the first case?

Has it to do with this bug?
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42949

Comment: What arguments are you passing to String.split() the first time?

Comment: When you say "it is splitting into separate strings after comma." -- what is splitting it? Where is this split happening?

Comment: Where do the strings come from? A file?

Comment: Hello, in order to understand the issue better can you please post the code where you initialize and fill your array "selecteddm"?

Comment: `str` is a `String` and not an array `String[]` so ofc you can't do `str.split("_")[1]`

Comment: `String[]` consists both the strings. I am doing `str.split("_")[1]` on each of those.

Comment: Looks like you are splitting the string on ',' and according to your code,all the outputs are expected result to me. what exactly are you expecting to have ?

Comment: `String[] selecteddm = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "selecteddm");` this is how i get the values in class file from jsp.

Comment: @khelwood: The string in second case with comma is automatically being split after comma. I am not doing it.

Comment: Seems like  ParamUtil.getParameterValues() is used for post request from forms. This function is normally used for reading the parameters of a multi select list which are comma-separated so it is splitting it using comma.
Try to escape or replace your commas before sending the form...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: after reading update disclosing use of Liferay

The root of the problem is that you are passing the display labels from the form instead of a key to identify them. You should pass form selections by key instead, like [this](http://mpatel3.blogspot.nl/2014/08/liferay-input-move-box.html):

```
List<User> userList = ...
List leftList = new ArrayList();
List rightList = new ArrayList();
for (int k = 0; k < userList.size(); k++) {
    User user = (User) userList.get(k);
    leftList.add(new KeyValuePair(String.valueOf(user.getUserId()), user.getScreenName()));
}
```

The second argument of the KeyValuePair is displayed to the user, the first argument is the key which is sent as part of a single, comma separated request parameter (containing all keys of selected items). You are supposed to identify the selection based on the keys, not the display labels.

[ParamUtil](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.java).getParameterValues is ultimately splitting the value by ",". This explains the behavior your are seeing.

BTW: that bug LPS-42949 seems fixed in the latest Liferay version. In any case it is not the cause of your problems.

Comment: I have edited the question with additional information about how the data is being passed from jsp to java.

Comment: I think there was a reason why I appended the value to the key as well `rightDataManagementList.add(new KeyValuePair(attribute.getAttributeListName()+"_"+attribute.getAttributeListValue(), attribute.getAttributeListValue()));`.  http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/42052103?_19_threadView=tree

Comment: It's an ugly hack but if you do that then you must ensure there are no comma's in the keys.